# Is there a cross between a relational database and Git?

Tags: persistent-storage

I'm looking for a programmatic way to store persistent data that's easily searchable on any field (like SQL) and keeps all of its history (like Git or a Wiki). I.e. if a bad value is saved, it can be reverted to a previous good value but without the complexity of having "previous value" tables for all tables.

I also need integrity between certain parts of the data, e.g. entities of both class A and class B must point to a valid entity of class C (not deleted), but class A and class B are not subsets or supersets of each other.

It must be as performant as a database but it doesn't have to be a database, it's just what I know and am used to. Is there a searchable persistent storage system that keeps its history and allows reversion of values (not the whole dataset at once)? If not, is there an easy way to use an existing product in this way?

Comment: Git in fact lets you revert a single file to any earlier revision.  With the help of a good GUI tool such as IntelliJ, it is also fairly easy to bring back any previous changes you want, file by file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not quite. Git allows you to checkout any previous version of a file which you can then persist as a new commit. The new commit does not refer to the old commit at all. There's no difference (except speed and fewer mistakes) between this and manually editing the file to its previous state. When you revert a whole commit, it refers to the commit you're reverting.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Fossil: https://www.fossil-scm.org/ It's an SCM that stores commits in a SQLite database and supports bidirectional syncing with git repos.